# How to read from keyboard in Swift 4.1.2?

Tags: swift, swift-playground, xcode9.1

This is not working

```
let input = readLine()
if let input = input {
    print(input) 
}
```

input is nil and I am using Xcode 9.1 at my Playground

Comment: In which environment are you? What does “does not work” mean exactly? Is `input` nil?

Comment: Yes input is nil and I am using Xcode 9.1 at my Playground